# Pantheon and Drupal: terminus/drush update --security-only

Tags: drupal-7, drush, pantheon

I'm using Drush over Pantheons terminus command-line tool, and trying to update my dev environment.

This command works just fine:

```
terminus drush [sitename].dev "pm-update"
```

However, I can't seem to pass the --security-only tag to drush in a way that will work.  I've tried numerous variations, including

```
terminus drush [sitename].dev "pm-update --security-only"
terminus drush [sitename].dev "pm-update" --security only
```

Etc.  Has anyone gotten this working?

Answer (score 0):

Terminus is best used just to generate drush aliases, I think.  Once it generates the aliases, just use garden-variety drush with those aliases.  When you're logged into terminus, use this command:

```
terminus aliases
```

then you can run commands you like, if you add the --strict=0 tag:

```
drush @[sitename].dev pm-update --security-only --strict=0
```